# Is there a way I can make a live search that searches my JSON file in html?

Tags: javascript, html

I've been looking through a lot of tutorials of how to do this but all of them I found couldn't help me.

I want to make a searchbox where people can search a waifu name if they put a keyword.

[This is how the JSON data looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SECBA.png)

```
{
    "waifuID": {
        "1": {
            "names": "Megumin",
            "img_url": "https://s4.anilist.co/file/anilistcdn/character/large/b89361-xH1t0q5WeAN8.png",
            "claims": "#1",
            "anime": "KonoSuba"
        },
        "2": {
            "names": "Mai Sakurajima",
            "img_url": "https://s4.anilist.co/file/anilistcdn/character/large/b127222-IY5iDRuXLY8i.png",
            "claims": "#2",
            "anime": "Seishun Buta Yarou wa Bunny Girl Senpai no Yume wo Minai"
        },
        "3": {
            "names": "Zero Two",
            "img_url": "https://s4.anilist.co/file/anilistcdn/character/large/b124381-pkTKi6HHNuVR.png",
            "claims": "#3",
            "anime": "Darling In The Franxx"
        }
    }
}
```

Im pretty sure you can use Object.values to find the name but I don't know how to actually structure the html file. Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is fully working code for you with `HTML` search functionality. You can use a `keyup` function to listen to the `keywords` typed into the inputs and see which `keyword` matched the `waifu` names

If you looking for the exact `waifu` name user has typed in then you can use `===` in my example below i am using [includes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/includes) function which search the string and output if any typed word matched the `waifu` names and then it display that `JSON` object.

**Live Working Demo:**

```js
function getwaifu(keyword) {
  //Display results
  let showResults = document.querySelector('#results')

  let data = {
    "waifuID": {
      "1": {
        "names": "Megumin",
        "img_url": "https://s4.anilist.co/file/anilistcdn/character/large/b89361-xH1t0q5WeAN8.png",
        "claims": "#1",
        "anime": "KonoSuba"
      },
      "2": {
        "names": "Mai Sakurajima",
        "img_url": "https://s4.anilist.co/file/anilistcdn/character/large/b127222-IY5iDRuXLY8i.png",
        "claims": "#2",
        "anime": "Seishun Buta Yarou wa Bunny Girl Senpai no Yume wo Minai"
      },
      "3": {
        "names": "Zero Two",
        "img_url": "https://s4.anilist.co/file/anilistcdn/character/large/b124381-pkTKi6HHNuVR.png",
        "claims": "#3",
        "anime": "Darling In The Franxx"
      }
    }
  }

  //fetch JSON
  if (keyword != '') {
    let output = Object.values(data.waifuID).find(waifu => waifu.names.toLowerCase().includes(keyword.toLowerCase()))
    if (output != undefined) {
      showResults.innerHTML = JSON.stringify(output)
    } else {
      showResults.innerHTML = 'No Results found'
    }
  } else {
    showResults.innerHTML = 'Please enter a keyword to search!'
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <title>Search JSON</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>

  <div class="container">
    <h2>Search waifu name</h2>
    <form>
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="exampleInputEmail1">Search JSON</label>
        <input type="email" onkeyup="getwaifu(this.value)" class="form-control" id="exampleInputEmail1" aria-describedby="emailHelp" placeholder="Enter a keyword">
        <small id="emailHelp" class="form-text text-muted">Enter a keyword.</small>
      </div>
      <div id="results"></div>
    </form>
  </div>

</body>

</html>
```

**Using Fetch API** to call your `JSON` file data (Code tested and working)

Here is the function you need to use if you want do a search when your JSON file is on the server or an API. In this we need to [fetch API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API) to get out JSON file and then do the object values and find functionality on one we have the results from that JSON file on the server.

```
function getwaifu(keyword) {
    //Display results
    let showResults = document.querySelector('#results')

    //fetch JSON
    if (keyword != '') {
        //Fetch API
        fetch('color.json')
        .then(res => res.json())
        .then((out) => {
            let output = Object.values(out.waifuID).find(waifu => waifu.names.toLowerCase().includes(keyword.toLowerCase()))
            if (output != undefined) {
                showResults.innerHTML = JSON.stringify(output)
            } else {
                showResults.innerHTML = 'No Results found'
            }
        }).catch(err => console.error(err));
    } else {
        showResults.innerHTML = 'Please enter a keyword to search!'
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks so much, I've been trying to figure out how to do this ❤❤❤

Comment: Hmm, your live working demo seems to work fine but when I try to fetch my actual database, nothing works.

I've also had this problem with ajax.

Comment: nvm, I fixed it by going into express and making a new endpoint that had my database and fetched it from there.

Comment: Is there any way I can display the waifus img_url aswell? Also, Is there a way I can display multiple?

Comment: @HK420 You are welcome. Yes if you are using node.js then you need to define a route to access the JSON from the backend. Also, in my demo its is showing **complete object** found so yeah you can access `img_url` from the search keyword as well.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Object.values()](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Objets_globaux/Object/values) to return an array where each object is an item in the array. After that, find your item with [Array.find()](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Objets_globaux/Array/find):

```
Object.values(waifuList.waifuID).find(waifu => waifu.names === "Zero Two")
```

```js
waifuList = {
    "waifuID": {
        "1": {
            "names": "Megumin",
            "img_url": "https://s4.anilist.co/file/anilistcdn/character/large/b89361-xH1t0q5WeAN8.png",
            "claims": "#1",
            "anime": "KonoSuba"
        },
        "2": {
            "names": "Mai Sakurajima",
            "img_url": "https://s4.anilist.co/file/anilistcdn/character/large/b127222-IY5iDRuXLY8i.png",
            "claims": "#2",
            "anime": "Seishun Buta Yarou wa Bunny Girl Senpai no Yume wo Minai"
        },
        "3": {
            "names": "Zero Two",
            "img_url": "https://s4.anilist.co/file/anilistcdn/character/large/b124381-pkTKi6HHNuVR.png",
            "claims": "#3",
            "anime": "Darling In The Franxx"
        }
    }
}
console.log(
  Object.values(waifuList.waifuID).find(waifu => waifu.names === "Zero Two")
)
```

Answer (score 0):

The Advanced for loop method is the easiest to iterate through the JSON and print the values.

```
for (var key in waifuList) {
for (var i = 0; i < waifuList[key].length; i++) {
    //HTML logic
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Another way would be to use indexOf with filter, it will also match partial strings.

Adding other columns to search in can be done in the same function.

```js
waifuList = {
  "waifuID": {
    "1": {
      "names": "Megumin",
      "img_url": "https://s4.anilist.co/file/anilistcdn/character/large/b89361-xH1t0q5WeAN8.png",
      "claims": "#1",
      "anime": "KonoSuba"
    },
    "2": {
      "names": "Mai Sakurajima",
      "img_url": "https://s4.anilist.co/file/anilistcdn/character/large/b127222-IY5iDRuXLY8i.png",
      "claims": "#2",
      "anime": "Seishun Buta Yarou wa Bunny Girl Senpai no Yume wo Minai"
    },
    "3": {
      "names": "Zero Two",
      "img_url": "https://s4.anilist.co/file/anilistcdn/character/large/b124381-pkTKi6HHNuVR.png",
      "claims": "#3",
      "anime": "Darling In The Franxx"
    }
  }
}

// partial of what might be searched. i.e autocomplete..
let search = 'Zero T'

console.log(
  Object.values(waifuList.waifuID).filter(v => {
    // look in name and anime
    if (v.names.indexOf(search) > -1 || v.anime.indexOf(search) > -1) return v
    return false
  })
)
```